# psycopg2 cursor.mogrify() formats query wrong way

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the following code:

```
args_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify("%s", (x,)) for x in full_list_of_bikes)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO bikes (id) VALUES" + args_str)
```

And the first line throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 103, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO bikes (id) VALUES" + args_str)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'W20409'"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO bikes (id) VALUES'W20409','W20756','W22626','W00...
```

`full_list_of_bikes` is a list of strings like this:

```
['W20409', 'W20756', 'W22626', 'W00980', 'W21338']
```

If I do a single insert with this code:

```
q = "INSERT INTO bikes (id) VALUES ('%s')" % bike_id
cur.execute(q)
```

Everything works fine. Am I doing something wrong? Or tables with only one columns should be handled somehow different with psycopg?

**Update:** `cur.mogrify("(%s)", (x,))` works. So I just added parenthesis.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no, looks like it is not ok: `INSERT INTO bikes (id) VALUES'W20409','W20756','W22626',....`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, I updated post. I changed code to `cur.mogrify("%s", (x,)) for x in full_list_of_bikes)` and now getting a little bit different error.

Comment: you're clearly missing the parentheses:

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, you're right! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I updated it with the solution, so I believe it looks now more consistent.